# Como inserir tabela excel no mysql usando php

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela no excel com mais de 300 linhas e gostaria de inserir os dados dessa tabela no mysql no phpmyadmin

uso php atualmente

Agradeço pela atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é um trabalho que vai ser feito apenas uma vez e/ou esta migrando de um excel para o seu banco, você pode baixar o `MySQL Installer` que tem várias ferramentas em:

- https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Aqui é demonstrado um preview dele:

- https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Agora se a intenção é realmente trabalhar documentos .xls e .xlsx com PHP via upload então recomendo que tenha em mente que boa parte você quem terá que desenvolver:

Primeiro será o upload do documento, usando [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Depois use o https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet para extrair os dados do documento, os formatos suportados pelo `PhpSpreadsheet` são:

- Open Document Format/OASIS (.ods)
- Office Open XML (.xlsx) Excel 2007
- BIFF 8 (.xls) Excel 97 and above
- BIFF 5 (.xls) Excel 95
- SpreadsheetML (.xml) Excel 2003
- Gnumeric
- HTML
- SYLK
- CSV

Para instalar é preciso usar o composer, se já tiver composer instalado então via CMD ou terminal navegue até a pasta do projeto e rode o comando:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Então no seu documento terá que ter algo como após o upload:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

... upload vai aqui ...

//Arquivo upload
$inputFileName = './upload/example1.xls';

$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
```

Então para acessar as celulas do documento use https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/

Por exemplo celular B8:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B8');
```